# Log-scale with concentrated data using integers

Tags: scales, logarithm

I have a data set with a range of 0 to 65,000.  The vast majority of data points (it is a huge sample) are concentrated between 0 and 1000.  There is only one point that has 65,000.  I want to plot this using a semi-logarithmic plot.  However, I would like the graph to have around 50 points.  If I use scales like 2,4,6,8,16,32,64,128,256 etc I have only a couple of points.  But If I use a multiple of 1.1 or 1.5 etc, the scales are not integers.  Is there a standard way to ensure you more concentrated intervals at a lower level on the scale?

Cheers,

s

Answer (score 3):

If you really only have one data point greater than 1000, it would be easiest just to delete that point from the graph. You can make a note in the caption or as a text box that there is an outlier.

Answer (score 2):

Can you just use a scale comprised of powers of (1+r) for some small r, and round to the nearest integer? For example, in R, with r = 0.25:

```
> x <- unique(round(1.25^(0:50)))
> x
 [1]     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     9    12    15    18    23    28    36    44    56    69    87   108   136   169   212   265   331   414
[26]   517   646   808  1010  1262  1578  1972  2465  3081  3852  4815  6019  7523  9404 11755 14694 18367 22959 28699 35873 44842 56052 70065
```

Comment: This is a resourceful approach and yet I wonder whether its benefits are outweighed by the problems it might pose for interpretability for some audiences.